# using PDO and getting "Call to a member function query() on a non-object"

Tags: php, mysql

I am basically using the same code that works in another scrip into this new class and somehow is not working. I really don't understand why is not working right now.

I keep getting the error "Call to a member function query() on a non-object"

Could anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

```
<?php
class ldcStepOne {
    public $JSON;
    private $db;

    public function __contruct () {
        $this->JSON = $JSON;
        $this->db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=X','X','X');
    }

    public function stepOne ( $JSON ) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ldc_user_details WHERE uID=101';
        $result = $this->db->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You typed `__contruct` instead of `__construct`. So that `$db` is never initialized.

Comment: Good eyes :) missed that completely

Comment: Thanks!... I really missed that one.